# Factorials of element of a list in two lines

Tags: python, function, lambda, list-comprehension, factorial

I have this code here which give us a factorial of each argument

```
def fac(*x):
for a in range(len(x)):
  r = 1
  for i in range(list(x).pop(a)):
     r+= r * i
  print("fac of ",x[a],"is :",r)
fac(6,7)
```

and I want to make it only in two lines
so I have tried this code:

```
import math
print("fac of "+str(6)+" is "+"\nfac of "+str(7)+" is \n".join( list(map(lambda f:math.factorial(f),[6,7]))))
```

but I had problem because join deal only with string not with number
anyone has another solution or could fix my code.

Answer (score 2):

`.join` only works on sequences of strings, so you need to make the `lambda` inside `map` return a string.

Use `str`:

```
... map(lambda f: str(math.factorial(f)), [6, 7])
```

As a side note, you don't need `list(...)`, since `join` will happily iterate over any iterable:

```
print("fac of " + str(6) + " is " + "\nfac of " + str(7) + " is \n".join(map(lambda f: str(math.factorial(f)), [6, 7])))
```

However, I don't think this produces the output you want.

Try this:

```
print("\n".join(map(lambda f: "fac of {} is {}".format(f, math.factorial(f)), [6, 7])))
```

This output is better, and:

- No need for all the calls to `str` because `.format` converts to string while interpolating.
- No need to specify the numbers multiple times
- The output dynamically grows as we add numbers to the array we pass to `map`